# Set to load collapsed but should load expanded - opposite way around functionality

Tags: php, html, yii

I have some code that loads a widget in a collapsed state on page load. I require this to not load in its collapsed state. I require it to have this functionality the opposite way around. Loads expanded, but can be collapsed with its toggle ability if desired.

I have tried and I cannot seem to figure it out. How do I solve this problem?

#### Attempt

```
public function run()
{
    if (isset($this->header)) {
        $tag = ArrayHelper::remove($this->headerOptions, 'tag');
        $header = $this->header .
            Html::tag('div', '', ['class' => 'd-flex flex-fill sidebar-menu-line']) .
            Html::button('<i class="fe fe-chevron-down"></i>', [
                'data-icon-show' => 'fe-chevron-down',
                'data-icon-hide' => 'fe-chevron-up',
                'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary btn-toggle-sidebar float-right d-block d-lg-none',
            ]);
        echo Html::tag($tag, $header, $this->headerOptions);
    }

    parent::run();
}
```

Comment: Are you using any technologies to expand and collapse the widget? jQuery, etc...?